# Test artifacts not present

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, expresso

Test artifacts column is not present in the build variants tab. I tried everything but still i'm unable to get the test artifacts column. My dependencies in app's build.gradle file look like as given below:

```
dependencies {
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':library:androidViewPagerIndicator')
    compile project(':library:camera')
    compile project(':library:ime')
    compile project(':nativebobblificationapi-release')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.+@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.10.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:0.0.1'
    //JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Mockito framework
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'

    androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test:runner:0.5"){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: starting from Android-Studio 2.0 both unit test and instrumentation tests are enabled simultaneously in the IDE. So, they have disabled Test artifacts column you have been looking for..no longer needed!

Comment: Since the test artifacts column is not present, i'm unable to see the androidTests folder in app/src.